# Reading input from std::cin TWICE

Tags: c++, input, iostream, cin

As I take input from cin using the cin.get function, it will automatically update the read location from the input file. What should I do to return the read location to the beginning of the file, so that I can take in the input a second time?

Say for instance I have the following file *input.txt*:

"Say hello to your new world"

and the following get loop to take in the input.txt file:

```
while(cin.get(charTemp)){
     numberOfChars++; 
}
```

How could I take in the input twice?

Comment: Why don't you just store the file contents in memory?

Comment: With file stream or string stream, you could use [`istream::seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), but you can't do this on standard input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to reread the standard input stream. If you really need to read the content twice you'll have to store it, e.g.:

```
std::stringstream input;
input << std::cin.rdbuf();
input.seekg(0);
// use input and seek back to the beginning if needed
```

Answer (score -1):

use `rewind(stdin)`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/ for reference.